# Comparing lists in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I could figure out some way to do this myself but I have a feeling there's a simpler, perhaps built-in way to do this. I want to see if any two lists share an element. These are the two lists I'm dealing with at the moment:

```
((0 1 2) (3 4 5) (6 7 8) (0 3 6) (1 3 7) (2 4 8) (0 4 8) (2 4 6))

((0 1 7) (0 1 6) (0 1 3) (0 3 7) (0 3 6) (0 6 7) (1 3 7) (1 3 6) (1 6 7) (3 6 7))
```

Since both lists contain `(1 3 7)`, I'd like a comparison of the lists to return `T`.

Is there a better way to do this than just setting up a couple `DOLIST`s?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about [INTERSECTION](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_intersect_intersection.html)?

```
(defvar a '((0 1 2) (3 4 5) (6 7 8) (0 3 6) (1 3 7) (2 4 8) (0 4 8) (2 4 6)))
=> A
(defvar b '((0 1 7) (0 1 6) (0 1 3) (0 3 7) (0 3 6) (0 6 7) (1 3 7) (1 3 6) (1 6 7) (3 6 7)))
=> B
(intersection a b :test 'equal)
=> ((1 3 7) (0 3 6))
```

Comment: Nice! That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks.